# How to disable the MacBook trackpad click but keep the tap enabled?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, trackpad, click

I have a 3-year-old Mac and either the battery or something else is broken (does not matter because it's not worth fixing) and due to this the trackpad keeps getting stuck.

Now my question is: can I disable the MacBook trackpad click function but keep tap enabled? This is so that I can still use the mac even though the trackpad is stuck.

Comment: Isn't this what tap-to-click is for? You tap the trackpad (not pressing hard enough to click) and the system registers it as a click.

Comment: no because when the click is stuck I cannot tap click anymore

Comment: Is there a separate trackpad button or is it the glass multitouch trackpad?

Comment: it is the multitouch trackpad -mac book pro 2009

Comment: [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) might have a way to do this.

Comment: Agh it's so annoying.  Why does Apple not let you customise things?  (Same with not being able to turn off pointer acceleration with the mouse).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that using vanilla Mac OS X. The trackpad allows to use tap function with click. It doesn't allow to use the tap exclusively.

However, there may be third-party software/kexts that allow to do that.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot find one...

Comment: This Apple Support Discussion might answer your question: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2322928?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: unfortunately its not very helpful, it just tells me how I can disable the trackpad while using a mouse... but thanks anyways